# After log in in ASP.NET website and page refresh httpContext.Request doesn't contain an auth cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, production

Good evening,

I have a website run on ASP.NET, login works perfectly for localhost but fails for production: if user logs in and refreshs the page then he is logged out by force. After some investingations I found out that this happens because of auth cookie,  it just doesn't present in the list of cookies in the _httpContext.Request (in method GetAuthenticatedCustomer(), because the auth cookie is missing, the _httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated is false and method returns null). However, I can see this cookie in browser, domain property is set correctly, it isn't expired and even if I set the expiration date manually, things don't change. Usage of FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name, true) doesn't help as well.

Here is the part of my FormsAuthenticationService code:

```
public virtual void SignIn(Customer customer, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();

        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1 /*version*/,
            _customerSettings.UsernamesEnabled ? customer.Username : customer.Email,
            now,
            now.Add(_expirationTimeSpan),
            createPersistentCookie,
            _customerSettings.UsernamesEnabled ? customer.Username : customer.Email,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        if (ticket.IsPersistent)
        {
            cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
        }
        cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL;
        cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain != null)
        {
            cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain;
        }

        _httpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        _cachedCustomer = customer;
    }

    public virtual void SignOut()
    {
        _cachedCustomer = null;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }

    public virtual Customer GetAuthenticatedCustomer()
    {
        if (_cachedCustomer != null)
            return _cachedCustomer;

        if (_httpContext == null ||
            _httpContext.Request == null ||
            !_httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated ||
            !(_httpContext.User.Identity is FormsIdentity))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var formsIdentity = (FormsIdentity)_httpContext.User.Identity;
        var customer = GetAuthenticatedCustomerFromTicket(formsIdentity.Ticket);
        if (customer != null && customer.Active && !customer.Deleted && customer.IsRegistered())
        {
            _cachedCustomer = customer;
        }

        return _cachedCustomer;
    }

    public virtual Customer GetAuthenticatedCustomerFromTicket(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        if (ticket == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ticket");

        var usernameOrEmail = ticket.UserData;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(usernameOrEmail))
            return null;
        var customer = _customerSettings.UsernamesEnabled
            ? _customerService.GetCustomerByUsername(usernameOrEmail)
            : _customerService.GetCustomerByEmail(usernameOrEmail);
        return customer;
    }
```

The only difference I notice between localhost and production is that at the production the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is missing too. However, I don't know how important it is.

[Cookies at production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n08Xq.png)

[Cookies at localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJIxc.png)

Part of my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Target framework is 4.5.

Comment: You have more than one servers in production?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, just one.

Comment: What is `_expirationTimeSpan`? Could it be a missing Setting on the productive server?

Comment: @Smartis, _expirationTimeSpan = 30.00:00:00.